# JNDI lookup failed from different VM

Tags: java, spring, jndi, lookup, hornetq

When doing a lookup on a JNDI server from within the same vm that started the server (being part of a spring web app), resources that are bound to JNDI (in this case JMS queue and connection factory) are returned as expected. When connecting to the JNDI server from a small standalone client app, it seems that there is nothing bound at all.

Does a JNDI server have different scopes concerning the resources bound to the directory and does it matter from which VM I start the lookup from?

Any help is appreciated.

**JNDI server is started as part of the spring context starup as follows:**

```
<bean name="namingServerImpl" class="org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="useGlobalService" value="true"/>
    <property name="installGlobalService" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean name="namingServer" class="org.jnp.server.Main" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="namingInfo" ref="namingServerImpl"/>
    <property name="port" value="1299"/>
    <property name="bindAddress" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="rmiPort" value="1298"/>
    <property name="rmiBindAddress" value="localhost"/>
</bean>
```

**jndi.properties is configured in classpath as follows:**

```
 java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
 java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
 java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1299
```

**Code sample for in-vm approach and standalone approach is the same:**

```
 InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

 NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = ctx.list("");
 while(list.hasMore()) {
     System.out.println(list.next().getName());
 }
```

The code snippet lists the expected resources when run in the same VM, but nothing when run in a small client app in a different VM.

Comment: perhaps the name scope is "java name space" and not "global name space", so that it's not accessible outside localhost..?